# How to attach remote stream and send it to another peer?

Tags: html, stream, chat, p2p, webrtc

I want to attach remote stream and send it to another peer, attach the remote stream like this:

```
firstPeer.onaddstream = function(remoteSteam) {
  otherPeer.addStream(remoteStream);  /* attaching remote stream */
};
```

But it doesn't work! (I can't receive this stream in another browser.)

Who can tell me How to attach remote stream? How to send remote stream to another peer?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm curious about this one too.  Would RTC allow a server to listen and record a stream between two peers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested it a [while ago](https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/issues/2). However, stream not flows if “remote stream” is attached.

I found that chrome missed many attributes when creating offer sdp, also offer sdp was set to “**recvonly**” instead of “**sendrecv**”.

In latest chrome canary, you can attach “remote stream” like this.

```
var newStream = new webkitMediaStream(remoteStream);
peer2.addStream(newStream);
```

Or otherwise:

```
var newStream = new webkitMediaStream([remoteStream.getAudioTracks(),remoteStream.getVideoTracks()]);
peer2.addStream(newStream);
```

In old chrome:

```
var newStream = new webkitMediaStream(remoteStream.audioTracks, remoteStream.videoTracks);
peer2.addStream(newStream);
```

To fill missed attributes in “offer sdp”; I used following coding:

```
sdp = sdp.replace(/a\=msid-semantic: WMS/g, 'a=msid-semantic: WMS ' + getChars());
sdp = sdp.replace(/recvonly/g, 'sendrecv')

var chars00 = getChars();
var numbers = getNumbers();

sdp += 'a=ssrc:'+ numbers+' cname:+Sb9HXiiNN/nhpZ1\r\n';
sdp += 'a=ssrc:'+ numbers+' msid:' + chars00 + ' v0\r\n';
sdp += 'a=ssrc:'+ numbers+' mslabel:' + chars00 + '\r\n';
sdp += 'a=ssrc:'+ numbers+' label:' + chars00 + '\r\n';

var replace = 'a=rtpmap:126 telephone-event/8000\r\n';
var chars00 = getChars();
var numbers = getNumbers();
replace += 'a=ssrc:'+ numbers+' cname:iecJoX+jqjkT8Dky\r\n';
replace += 'a=ssrc:'+ numbers+' msid:' + chars00 + '\r\n';
replace += 'a=ssrc:'+ numbers+' mslabel:' + chars00 + '\r\n';
replace += 'a=ssrc:'+ numbers+' label:' + chars00;
sdp = sdp.replace(/a\=rtpmap:126 telephone-event\/8000/g, replace)
```

Remember, “getChars” and “getNumbers” methods returns random values.

[A demo to test](https://googledrive.com/host/0B6GWd_dUUTT8V1Fodm9WQldkb28/).